# Bash md5 does not set by Elixir md5 creator

Tags: elixir

for verify file size in the 2 system . I did create code like blow in elixir

```
def file_md5_creator do
    filepath = "/Users/shahryar/Desktop/test.jpg"       
    File.stream!(filepath) |>
    Enum.reduce(:crypto.hash_init(:md5),
    fn(line, acc) -> :crypto.hash_update(acc,line) end ) |>
    :crypto.hash_final |> Base.encode16(case: :lower)
end
```

but Bash md5 does not set by elixir md5 creator

> elixir md5 : ee4ed0f9c357b7d803d08f7d75dd983b
>
> bash : 53a3107b118854f20c5af6269a434981

bash command =

```
md5 /Users/shahryar/Desktop/test.jpg
```

My os : mac

Pleas help me for problem

Comment: Your code's output matches the output of `md5` utility from command line for me when I test against a random jpg file. Can you upload your file somewhere?

Comment: @Dogbert , my all of code was written in first post. i had not any files.

Comment: This file: `/Users/shahryar/Desktop/test.jpg`.

Comment: @Dogbert excuse me : http://s9.picofile.com/file/8307835984/test.jpg

Comment: Thanks, my test image was very small and didn't contain "\r\n" so my output was correct. Your image helped me figure out the cause and I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File.stream!` defaults to reading files in "line" mode which normalizes the `"\r\n"` newline sequence to `"\n"`.

```
iex(1)> File.write!("a", "a\r\nb\r\nc")
:ok
iex(2)> File.read!("a")
"a\r\nb\r\nc"
iex(3)> File.stream!("a") |> Enum.into("")
"a\nb\nc"
```

To make `File.stream!` not do that, you can make it read in bytes mode, by specifying an integer as the third argument, which is the number of bytes to read at a time.

```
iex(4)> File.stream!("a", [], 16384) |> Enum.into("")
"a\r\nb\r\nc"
```

Your image contains `"\r\n"` in several places which means the raw data is corrupted by `File.stream!` and you get the wrong MD5 hash value. If you change your `File.stream!` call's third argument to an integer, it should work correctly:

```
File.stream!(filepath, [], 16384) |>
```